# Validation based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I am trying to use Excel .Validation to validate a field based on two criteria:

1) value is in a range  OR   2) value is whole number.

I am getting compile errors when I try to do 2 .Add calls
I am starting to think I may have to use a custom formula.

Can someone help me with a custom formula that will check to see if the value is in the range strRange OR a number between 1 and 256?

```
ElseIf Target.Column >= BaseColIndex And Target.Column Mod 2 > 0 And Cells(10, Target.Column).Value <> "" Then
    strNormOper = Cells(10, Target.Column).Value
    strRange = IIf(strNormOper = "open", "$AC2:$AC5", "$AE2:$AE5")
    strValidation = "=" & Worksheets("Lookups").name & "!" & strRange
    With Target.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=strValidation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateWholeNumber, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="1", Formula2:="256"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .ErrorTitle = "Validation Error"
        .ErrorMessage = "Must be the opposite of 'Normal Operation' for this output Or a number in the range 1 To 256."
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

Comment: I would have to agree - a custom formula is probably required.  I am thinking something like the following:  `"=OR(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH("&Target.Address&","&strRange&",0))),IFERROR(AND(INT("&Target.Address&")="&Target.Address&","&Target.Address&">0,"&Target.Address&"<257),0))"`  I have not tested it, but hopefully the idea is clear.

Comment: Thank you, the idea did help, I had to customize it a bit due to a couple details I left out.    `strValidation = "=OR(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(" & Target.Address & ", Lookups!" & strRange & ", 0))), IFERROR(ISNUMBER(INT(" & Cells(Target.row, Target.Column).Address & ")), FALSE))" `

Comment: @Demetri can you kindly add your suggestion as an answer so Michaela can mark this post as answered? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original suggested solution, was the below custom formula:

```
"=OR(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH("&Target.Address&","&strRange&",0))),IFERROR(AND(INT("&T‌​arget.Address&")="&Target.Address&","&Target.Address&">0,"&Target.Address&"<257),‌​0))"
```

which Michaela expanded on for her solution:

```
strValidation = "=OR(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(" & Target.Address & ", Lookups!" & strRange & ", 0))), IFERROR(ISNUMBER(INT(" & Cells(Target.row, Target.Column).Address & ")), FALSE))"
```

EDIT: I used to above first but then figured out how to edit your answer to completely fill my needs.  The problem was that Target.Address is two merged cells so the value was always blank.  The following fixed it while using (almost) your original solution.

```
strValidation = "=OR(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(" & Target.Address & ", Lookups!" & strRange & ", 0))), IFERROR(AND(INT(" & Cells(Target.row, Target.Column).Address & ") > 0, INT(" & Cells(Target.row, Target.Column).Address & ") < 257), FALSE))"
```